# Customize Lightning:helpText popup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds

I've tried to modify the style of the lightning:helptext popover by following [Tooltips- Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tooltips/#Styling-Hooks-Overview), but it's not working.
Here's my code:

```
        <lightning:helptext iconVariant="inverse" iconName="utility:comments" content="{!v.attachment.comment}" class="commentsIcon" />
```

CSS:

```
.THIS .commentsIcon {
--sds-c-tooltip-color-background: rgba(243, 242, 242, 1) !important;
--sds-c-tooltip-text-color: #333333 !important;
```

}

But here's the result:[image]

Is it possible to change the style ?